# Using plyer with kivy. Weird errors.

Tags: python, kivy

I have been trying to figure out what's wrong with this code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.clock import Clock
from plyer.facades import accelerometer



class Accel(Widget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.sensorEnabled = False

    def get_acceleration(self, dt):
        val = accelerometer.acceleration

        self.ids.label1.text = "X: " + str(val[0])
        self.ids.label2.text = "Y: " + str(val[1])
        self.ids.label3.text = "Z: " + str(val[2])

    def pressed1(self):
        try:
            if not self.sensorEnabled:
            # accelerometer.enable()
                Clock.schedule_interval(self.get_acceleration, 1 / 20.)
                self.sensorEnabled = True
                self.ids.button1.text = "Stop"
            else:
                # accelerometer.disable()
                Clock.unschedule(self.get_acceleration)
                self.sensorEnabled = False
                self.ids.button1.text = "Start"
        except:

            self.ids.status.text = "Accelerometer not supported"


class e3App(App):
    def build(self):
        return Accel()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    e3App().run()
```

What happens is when I run it and press the START button it crashes and gives me this:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):    File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/plyer/platforms/linux/accelerometer.py",
> line 22, in _get_acceleration
>      pos = glob.glob("/sys/devices/platform/*/position")[0]  IndexError: list index out of range    During handling of the above
> exception, another exception occurred:    Traceback (most recent call
> last):    File
> "/home/rickdps/Desktop/KivyCookBook/InputMotionAndTouch/WorkingWithAccelerometer/main.py",
> line 42, in <module>
>      e3App().run()    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/kivy/app.py", line 828, in run
>      runTouchApp()    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/kivy/base.py", line 504, in
> runTouchApp
>      EventLoop.window.mainloop()    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/kivy/core/window/window_sdl2.py",
> line 663, in mainloop
>      self._mainloop()    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/kivy/core/window/window_sdl2.py",
> line 405, in _mainloop
>      EventLoop.idle()    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/kivy/base.py", line 339, in
> idle
>      Clock.tick()    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/kivy/clock.py", line 581, in
> tick
>      self._process_events()    File "kivy/_clock.pyx", line 367, in kivy._clock.CyClockBase._process_events
> (/tmp/pip-build-rau3eo9p/kivy/kivy/_clock.c:7700)    File
> "kivy/_clock.pyx", line 397, in
> kivy._clock.CyClockBase._process_events
> (/tmp/pip-build-rau3eo9p/kivy/kivy/_clock.c:7577)    File
> "kivy/_clock.pyx", line 395, in
> kivy._clock.CyClockBase._process_events
> (/tmp/pip-build-rau3eo9p/kivy/kivy/_clock.c:7498)    File
> "kivy/_clock.pyx", line 167, in kivy._clock.ClockEvent.tick
> (/tmp/pip-build-rau3eo9p/kivy/kivy/_clock.c:3490)    File
> "/home/rickdps/Desktop/KivyCookBook/InputMotionAndTouch/WorkingWithAccelerometer/main.py",
> line 15, in get_acceleration
>      val = accelerometer.acceleration[:3]    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/plyer/utils.py", line 103, in
> __getattribute__
>      return getattr(object.__getattribute__(self, '_obj'), name)    File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/plyer/facades/accelerometer.py",
> line 44, in acceleration
>      return self.get_acceleration()    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/plyer/facades/accelerometer.py",
> line 60, in get_acceleration
>      return self._get_acceleration()    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/plyer/platforms/linux/accelerometer.py",
> line 24, in _get_acceleration
>      raise Exception('Could not enable accelerometer!')  Exception: Could not enable accelerometer!
```

I am following this book called "Kivy Cook Book", and I've mostly copied and pasted code in order to try it. This one has not worked though.

I'd really appreciate any help.

Comment: Does the computer you're running this on even HAVE an accelerometer?  The error is not being caught by your try/except because the first actual access to the hardware happens later, during a scheduled call to `get_acceleration()` - you need to put the error check there.

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning the fact that this also happens when I run it on an  actual device which I believe has an accelerometer.  Could you please tell me how would I go about putting the error check there ...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39761977/plyer-accelerometer-not-implemented-error-on-android-phone